# How to organize shared functions in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I need create a lot functions, used by 6+ Controllers. So... **shared functions**:

This functions **needs**:

- Model Access
- Database Access
- Lib Access
- Vendor Access
- Plugin Access
- View Redirect
- Return parameters (callback)

What the **best way**?

- Lib
- Component
- Behavior
- Vendor

My website **configuration**:

- CakePHP 2.3
- MySQL 5.5
- PHP 5.3.9
- Apache 2.2

---

Sorry for my english.
Thanks.

Comment: Go with Components it wil work well and also easy to access

Comment: View Redirect? There is no such thing. Only normal redirects via controller/request object

Comment: I don't know. I just want detail my question. Anyway, I'll try components, but I don't know if is a good pratice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Helpers are for (multiple) views
Behaviors are for (multiple) models
Tasks are for (multiple) shells
Components are for (multiple) controllers
```

So - if you share those functions across controllers, the logical answer would be to use components.

All the rest of your "options" provided fail for at least one reason.

But keep in mind that you still have to keep the model stuff close to the model layer and should only use it via model methods in the controller/components.
Don't make those components a powerful model or something. They are meant to share "logic" between controllers.

Comment: So, If component execute some operations (compare, sum), and select/insert some information in database, it's correct?

Comment: But I mean: load model in component, and call "insert/select" functions. Understand? Can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you can use models via ClassRegistry::init() or via controller and use them just as you would from any controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can write those function in Appcontroller  file so you can access them globally.